# Are cherry leaves naturally droopy?

Tags: fruit-trees, leaves, cherries

I have 4 cherry varieties grafted onto one rootstock. They are Royal Ann, Bing, Black Tartarian, and Lapins. It was planted in a dormant state in January 2014 in zone 9. It gets at least 8 hours of sunlight every day. I give it 2 gallons of water every weekend. I have not fertilized it.

It now is flourishing with leaves, but all of them are droopy. Is this the natural tendency of cherry leaves? If not, how do I fix it? The majority of leaves are blemish free. There's only 2 leaves that have been chewed through by an unknown insect.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they do tend to point downwards, although if your weather is very warm and dry, it may need a couple of gallons twice a week for the first year. Looks pretty healthy to me, but keep up the watering - if it flowers this year, then remember to increase watering when/if fruit starts to form, particularly during dry spells.

UPDATE: If it flowered, its ready to fruit. The flowers it had either weren't fertilised and fell naturally, or there was a water shortage and they just shrivelled, though sometimes heavy cold can shrivel them before fertilisation. I don't see any signs of flowers remaining on the tree indicating other problems, and everything looks pretty healthy from the picture.

Comment: It produced just 2 flowers soon after I planted it early this year. They never turned into fruit. It may not be fruiting age yet - it is only 5 feet tall.